# Will upgrading Windows 7 to 8 affect Ubuntu installation (dual-boot)?

Tags: 12.04, installation, upgrade, dual-boot, windows

I'm posting this question because I have the intention to update my Windows 7 (damaged installation) to Windows 8 but I don't know if this process may affect my Ubuntu 12.04 install. I have 220 GB dedicated to Windows, 65 GB to Ubuntu, a 10 GB Recovery and 1.5 GB swap partition.

And one final doubt: Is it recommended to update Ubuntu to 12.10? If the answer is yes, how can I guarantee a safety update?

Answer (score 3):

You can upgrade Windows from 7 to 8. I did it and it did not effect my Ubuntu Installation in any way.

If in-case you loose the Ubuntu boot option ( Grub is replaced with windows boot loader ), Then to fix this issue you will only need to Boot your computer with a live Ubuntu USB stick And run this command in the terminal

```
update-grub
```

I would recommend you to update From 12.04 to 12.10 Cos of cool new features and much improved look, feel, speed and Performance. :)

Answer (score 3):

My answer is "No". Upgradation of Windows will not affect on your Ubuntu 12.04 , because you have installed on another partition. If you loose grub loader after installation of windows 8 , you can install it again. Check out [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169108/windows-7-pro-wont-load-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-lts/195013#195013) to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 2nd question: Upgrading Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 - doesn’t affect to another systems on computer, it is safely for other systems. I tried it with previous Ubuntu versions and with 12.10 too.